# Which services are identified in conn.log by Bro?

Tags: bro

I am looking for the list of services that bro/zeek identifies in `conn.log`. But I am unable to find out exactly how many services Bro identifies. Where can I get the correct script le, source code or documentation where I can get the list of services that Bro detects?

E.g. this documentation section just mentions that

```
application-layer services ( - the service field is filled in as Bro determines a specific protocol to be in use, independent of the connection’s ports),
```

But where are these services defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is a bit complex, because it depends on the set of protocol analyzers present on your system and how they are configured (i.e., how/whether Zeek may select them for individual connections).

That said, [this list](https://docs.zeek.org/en/stable/script-reference/proto-analyzers.html#type-Analyzer::Tag) defines the set of supported analyzers. There may be more if you install additional ones on your system via the package manager.

The nitty-gritty details are spelled out in [the original paper](http://www.icir.org/robin/papers/usenix06.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christian, much appreciated.

Comment: Let me also link Anthony Kasza's [answer on the mailing list](http://mailman.icsi.berkeley.edu/pipermail/zeek/2019-May/014236.html), since it does a great job narrowing down the analyzer list to protocol ones, and getting the exact strings you were hoping for.